What is a pre vote?
As seen in

New Vote Types in latest data dump?,

some new vote types appeared (likely) exclusively in the Stack Overflow data dump. A couple users helped find out what each one meant. However, what VoteTypeId 31 “preVote” meant was unknown.
Nothing else about it is in moderator.en.js and searching meta Stack Overflow seems to give no information either. Perhaps it is something done before a vote is actually cast, but it is not clear. Since the quoted question is asked on meta and it is about the data dump, it will be asked here.
What is a “pre vote”?

It's probably related to this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429682/we-will-launch-the-1-rep-voting-experiment-on-stack-overflow-for-4-6-weeks-alon

For completeness, this vote type (along with every vote type with an ID > 16) is now filtered out of the data dumps.

Well it's for internal SE developers usage, so we can't really know, and not sure we need to know. But yeah, it's "nice to know". :)

Might also be the "pre-upvote" you can cast on Staging Ground posts, upvoting them when published
